# angular directive leaking child contents out

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, content-model

I have a custom tag `<my-tag>` created with an Angular directive, and replace it with a simple `<div>` in the directive definition code:

```
.directive('myTag',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>contents in template</div>',
    replace: true
  }
})
```

Things get strange when I put this tag inside a `<p>` tag and have some block element in it (for later transcluding maybe):

```
<p>
    <my-tag><div>leak</div></my-tag>
</p>
```

the rendered html is something like this:

```
<p><div>contents in template</div></p>
<div>leak</div>
```

rather than been replaced as a whole, the `<div>leak</div>` is leaked out. Firstly I thought this might be some inline/block element issue, since the `<p>` tag is only allowed to have [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) in it. But when I switched it to `<pre>`, `<h1>`, `<span>`(they all have the same restrictions in the content model), I don't have the problem anymore:

```
<span>
    <my-tag><div>leak</div></my-tag>
</span>
```

rendered html (as expected):

```
<span><div>contents in template</div></span>
```

This could be a big problem when tries to transclude the contents - they are completely unavailable in the directive.

Here is a plunker for the live demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hOByDb

<del>Frankly I'm not sure whether this is a browser issue or a Angular issue, or maybe is just an intended behavior?</del>

Edit:

I think this is rather a common HTML issue than an Angular issue, but it's more likely to happen in an Angular project, since we tend to have many custom directives/tags there.

Comment: putting `div` in `p` is unusual, never seen it done. Changing first `<p>` to `<div>` and problem dissapears

Comment: Yes but shouldn't the same rule apply to `<h1>`, `<span>` as well?

Comment: what rule are you referring to? Your html must be valid or you will get unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C docs ( HTML4 & HTML5), block level elements are not valid children of `<p>`. This is cause of your problem

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

[Reference docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)